# WordPress float in article

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float

I made a website with WordPress and I have a problem with my float in my article.

http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_756574Capturedcran20141013181858.png

Has you can see, when the sidebar finish, the content go to the left and I don't want that. I want the content always in the right. I want all the content below the other.

My code:

html (all my article is on the  a  tag:

```
<div id="container">
<aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
code of the sidebar here...
</aside>
<article id="post-53" class="post-53 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-non-classe">code of article here...</aticle>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin-top:-3%; 
}
aside{
    width:30%;
    text-align:left;
    max-width:280px;
    padding:2%;
    float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    height: 100%;
}
article  {
    background-color: #fff;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    margin:1%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-left:4%;
    padding:2%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    max-width:550px;
    float:left;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try floating the article to the right instead of left as it is now?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a container element around your articles, and float the container instead of individual articles. Give that article container a specific width like 48% (or whatever). As long as the width of your aside and the width of the article container, along with padding/margins, adds up to 100% or less, they will live next to each other. All the articles will stay inside their container instead of slipping back left. The problem you're having now is due to the fact that your articles have the same parent element (`#container`) as the `aside`. Once there are enough articles to push down past the aside, they will float left against their parent container (`#container`).

For example, you can wrap a div around the articles like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">code of the sidebar here...</aside>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <article id="post-53" class="post-53 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-non-classe">code of article here...</article>
        <article id="post-54" class="post-54 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-non-classe">code of article here...</article>
        <article id="post-55" class="post-55 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-non-classe">code of article here...</article>
        <article id="post-56" class="post-56 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-non-classe">code of article here...</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
#content-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

Be sure to remove the float from your articles, and watch your spelling -- the closing tag on `</article>` is spelled incorrectly in your HTML.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwaxy073/1/